# Rails get Model :id via Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, post

I am looking for a way to access a model via its :id.

My project looks like this:

First someone can register himself in a form. Then he gets forwarded to a page where he can edit the things he entered. Now I do not want that you can see something in the URL.

Edit:

I was maybe a little unclear:

There is a form, where you can enter some things. After you submitted those things, you will be forwarded to another page with an URL like 'www.example.com/entry'. There I want to show what the person entered. And I do not want an URL like 'www.example.com/entry?id=12'

I hope that clarified some things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is a bit lacking in details, so I'll do my best here. Essentially, if you do not want to display the url parameters, then you will have to use the `post` HTTP method to submit your forms (which you should be doing anyway).

In your `routes.rb` file, you'll need to define your route to look something like this:

```
post 'route', to: 'controller#action'
```

Data submitted via the `post` method is typically submitted via a form. I would recommend using rails conventions like:

- the rails `form_for` helper --> [more details](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)
- `resources` since they typically give you the routes you want. To modify your routes beyond the defaults, I'd advise looking at the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).